# Is there a command to either open a website or focus an open browser tab?

Tags: command-line, firefox

I'd love to be able to run a command such as `firefox mail.google.com` and have it:

1. Open the site in a new browser tab if it isn't already open (what calling firefox does by default)
2. Focus the tab for that domain if it is already active in a browser tab

Is this possible? I didn't find anything like this in the [Firefox command line options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible just run the command in the terminal.  You may, in some cases, have to specify the `http://` protocol.

You can do that with:

```
$ firefox http://mail.google.com
```

By the way, that command might not go directly in to the mail program.  It credential would have to be saved in the browser.  Since `Firefox` isn't my default browser, in my case using:

```
$ google.com http://mail.google.com
```

That will do exactly what you described for me since I called the site from the browser I use.

An alternate command to get the correct browser is:

```
$ xdg-open http://mail.google.com
```

**Update:**

This commandline will focus the current tab or create a new one if gmail isn't already open (the first dollar sign `$` is the command prompt.  The command is everything after the command prompt).

```
$ [[ $(wmctrl -l|egrep "@gmail.*Firefox") ]]&&wmctrl -a $(wmctrl -l|egrep "@gmail.*Firefox"|awk '{print $7}')||firefox http://mail.google.com
```

Rather than trying to type or paste the long commandline, you can just make a bash script called `firefoxmail`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

[[ $(wmctrl -l|egrep "@gmail.*Firefox") ]]&&wmctrl -a $(wmctrl -l|egrep "@gmail.*Firefox"|awk '{print $7}')||firefox http://mail.google.com
```

Then call it with `firefoxmail`  The `.sh` extension is optional since you have the `shebang` at the top and have the exec bit set.

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me. Calling `firefox http://mail.google.com` opens up a new tab even it's already open. I've updated my question a bit in case it was unclear what I was asking.

Comment: @jncraton I ammended the answer with this cli: `[[ $(wmctrl -l | egrep "@gmail.*Firefox") ]] && wmctrl -a $(wmctrl -l | egrep "@gmail.*Firefox" | awk '{print $7}') || firefox http://mail.google.com`

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, this still doesn't work for me. At least on my system, wmctrl only enumerates each window, not each tab. This will focus firefox if it already has the desired tab active, but will open a new session otherwise. `wmctrl -l` only returns one item per firefox windows, not per firefox tab on my system.

Comment: Sorry.  I tested it.  I don't use tabs.  I'll have to setup tabs on my firefox and modify the command.  Thanks for the feedback.